# Find the best R2 by lopping through a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I am learning pandas and NumPy. I am trying to write a script that will loop through a dataframe and calculate the R2 of an increasingly larger number of rows. This is what I came up with for now:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df=pd.DataFrame()
a=[1, 1.5, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
b=[2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
df['a']=a
df['b']=b
print(df)

plt.scatter(x=df['a'], y=df['b'])
lr = LinearRegression()
for i in range(len(df)):
    n=0
    X=np.column_stack([np.ones(len(df), dtype=np.float32),(df['a'].loc[0+n]).values()])
    y=(df['b'].loc[0+n])
    n=n+1
    model = lr.fit(X,y)
    print(f'R Squared: {model.score(X,y)}')
```

But I only get the error:

```
'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'values'
```

When I use `.values` without the `for`-loop, it converts the values without any problem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your goal, but `(df['a'].loc[0+n])` results in a single number, not a Series, so you can't call .values() on it.

I've added some hopefully helpful comments to parts of your code
Can you please clarify what you expect `X` to be in each iteration of the loop?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df=pd.DataFrame()
a=[1, 1.5, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
b=[2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
df['a']=a
df['b']=b
print(df)

plt.scatter(x=df['a'], y=df['b'])
lr = LinearRegression()

n=0 #I moved this outside the for-loop. before n would always be reset to 0 in each iteration of the for-loop

#you can also consider using i instead of n since i 

for i in range(len(df)):
    print('n =',n,'i =',i) #keep track of what n and i are
    X=np.column_stack([
        np.ones(len(df), dtype=np.float32), #first column is all ones
        #(df['a'].loc[0+n]).values()  #do you need to add 0?
        np.repeat(df['a'].loc[n], len(df)), #did you want the second column to all be the n-th value of column A?
    ])
    y=(df['b'].loc[0+n]) #do you need to add 0?
    n=n+1
    
    print(X)
    
    #skipping the below for now
    #model = lr.fit(X,y) #Error! complains it can't fit since "TypeError: Singleton array array(2) cannot be considered a valid collection."
    #print(f'R Squared: {model.score(X,y)}')
```